# C# Polymorphism: subclass with extra fields

Tags: c#, winforms, polymorphism

I have a class called Materials from where subclasses Cylinders and Bars inherit from. Bars has an 3 extra fields while Cylinders have only 2 extra fields.

```
public abstract class Material
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Density { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; protected set; }
    public abstract void CalculateWeight();
}

public class Cylinder : Material
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Radius { get; set; }

    public override void CalculateWeight()
    {
        Weight = Density * (Math.PI * Math.Pow(Radius, 2));
    }
}

public class Bars : Material
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public override void CalculateWeight()
    {
        Weight = Density * Length * Width * Height;
    }
}
```

I'm using these classes in a Windows Form and for every TextBoxes(for Density etc.) or Comboboxes, I have to use a switch case to know which subclass I'm going to generate either a Cylinder or a Bar since I can't generally use the base class. For instance, I have many of these:

(TxtBox2 is the same textbox used for either Radius or Width)

```
private void TxtBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(ComboBoxMaterialType.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
        Cylinder currentCylinder.Radius = TxtBox2.Text;
    case 1:
        Bar currentBar.length = TxtBox2.Text;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this and just use the base class instead of having to declare two objects of *Cylinder* and *Bar*? I know that one thing I could do is just put all the parameters (*Length*, *Radius*, *Width*, *Height*) in the base class which just leaves only the overridden *CalculateWeight*() function in the derived classes. With this, I can just declare one *Material* object and fill out the parameters from each textbox and I can call the *CalculateWeight* from this single object. But I feel like that that's defeating the concept of inheritance and polymorphism since NOT ALL *Material* object has a *Radius* or *Height* even though I can leave them as *null*.

Comment: Why can't there be separate sets of UI inputs for each `Material` type? "overloading" textboxes, variables, booleans, whatever for multiple things is not a good thing. Your question demonstrates that it does not save time, code, or brain power.

Comment: Yes I can do that but it still doesn't remove the problem that I have to declare two objects on the form, one for Cylinder and one for Bar.

Comment: I think it's a matter of design. If you want a single class you'll need to group all properties in a single type and discriminate it with one more property (e.g. named `Kind`, maybe an enumeration). Anyway I don't think it could be a good choice. A good model of business concepts should always have prioriority.

Comment: @radarbob Furthermore, my Form would be more cluttered if I have two different textboxes each for *Cylinder* and *Bar*. For instance, if I would not use a switch case, I would have to put two textBoxes for *Name* property for two different object *Cylinder* and *Bar*... That is why I'm trying to find a way to have just a single object for two different subclasses...

Comment: Listen to @gsscoder! Also, perhaps a tab for each material-type; modular and extensible. Or, group base properties and each type separately with no redundancies. Use labels, dividing lines, etc. so the user will see the commonality and differences - a good thing I should think. A "create" button for each solves the context problem, and the problem of entering some or all field values for more than one type. Do not have any "what class am I" logic at all in the UI field handlers.